# Can't test nulls in Oracle Pro*C

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I am beginner about Pro*c Oracle and C. When I practice example base on Oracle Pro*c document, I can't test Nulls which use indicator, reference [Oracle Pro*c guide link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpcc/embedded-SQL.html#GUID-1560EFD0-EF58-45B1-AF97-4110307D7501)(I am not sure my code is correct).

> > ### Oracle document write:
> >
> > 6.2.4 Test for NULLs
> >     You can use indicator variables in the WHERE clause to test for NULLs, as the following example shows:
> >
> > EXEC SQL SELECT ename, sal INTO :emp_name, :salary 
> >     FROM emp 
> >     WHERE :commission INDICATOR :ind_comm IS NULL ...

My code as follows:

```
Locations table:

+-------------+---------+---------+
| Location_Id | Address | Country |
+-------------+---------+---------+
|           1 | London  |  London |
|           2 | US      |    null |
+-------------+---------+---------+


void connect()
{
    /* Connect to ORACLE. */
    strcpy(username, "hr");
    strcpy(password, "hr");

    EXEC SQL DECLARE DB_NAME DATABASE;
    EXEC SQL CONNECT : username IDENTIFIED BY : password;
    printf("\nConnected to ORACLE as user: %s\n", username);
}

void testNull()
{
    short country_ind = -1;
    char address[20];
    char *country = "country";
    EXEC SQL SELECT ADDRESS INTO :address FROM LOCATIONS
    WHERE :country INDICATOR :country_ind is null;
    /*
Current, it always output address is London instead of US
 */
        printf("address :%d\n", address);
    }

void main()
{
    connect();
    testNull();
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your SQL queries, it seems they lost the operators , and furthermore , I do not see correspondance between your queries and the table

Comment: @Gar, I updated your comment, thanks. I am write sql in Oracle Pro*c

Answer (score 0):

The use of indicator is not "indicated" here (unintended pun)

I would have written it this way

```
void testNull()
{
    short country_ind = -1;
    char address[20];
    char *country = "country";
    EXEC SQL SELECT ADDRESS INTO :address FROM LOCATIONS
    WHERE country  is null;
    /*
Current, it always output address is London instead of US
 */
        printf("address :%d\n", address);
    }
```

And you can use an indicator for the addess should you need to check if it is null afterwards

If you want the "country" to be a variable
then your code should be something like :

```
void testNull()
{
    short country_ind = 0;   // the word "country" is not null, but the value of the field can be depending on the query/data
     char address[20];
   char *country = "country";
EXEC SQL SELECT ADDRESS INTO :address FROM LOCATIONS
WHERE :country INDICATOR :country_ind is null;
/*
Current, it always output address is London instead of US
 */
        printf("address :%d\n", address);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. First way work fine, but second way not work. I will continue with first way to avoid taking time

Comment: Welcome !, please do not hesitate to accept the answer should it suit your needs.